# Speech to Text (Webkit) just visible in console. How to print into text field?

Tags: javascript, html, webkit, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

I would like to do an application with speech to text with webkit for chrome. It works fine but I just can't get my spoken text into a dedicated field, it's showing up at the console though... It should appear in the same textfield where I can also write. Attached you can find a part of my HTML/JS.... I can also post the whole file if necessary.

```html
        <label for="textInput" class="inputOutline">
          <input id="textInput" class="input responsive-column"
            placeholder="Type something" type="text"
            onkeydown="/*globals CanvasJS */
            ConversationPanel.inputKeyDown(event, this)">
        </label>


<button onclick="startConverting();"><i class="fa fa-microphone"></button> <!-- NEW TILL /SCRIPT-->
<script type="text/javascript">

 var r = document.getElementById('textInput');

 function startConverting (){

  if('webkitSpeechRecognition' in window){
 var speechRecognizer = new webkitSpeechRecognition();
 speechRecognizer.continuous = true;
 speechRecognizer.interimResults = true;
 speechRecognizer.lang = 'en-IN';
 speechRecognizer.start();

 var finalTranscripts = '';

 speechRecognizer.onresult = function(event){
          var interimTranscripts = '';
          for(var i = event.resultIndex; i < event.results.length; i++){
           var transcript = event.results[i][0].transcript; 
           transcript.replace("\n", "<br>");
           if(event.results[i].isFinal){
            finalTranscripts += transcript;
           }else{
            interimTranscripts += transcript;
           }

          }

          r.innerHTML = finalTranscripts + '<span style="color#999' +interimTranscripts + '</span>'; 
 };

 speechRecognizer.onerror = function (event) {

 };
}else {
 r.innerHTML = 'use google chrome';
}

 }



</script>
```

The console is showing me this.... But the text needs to appear on the screen.

```html
<input id="textInput" class="input responsive-column" placeholder="Type something" type="text" onkeydown="/*globals CanvasJS */
            ConversationPanel.inputKeyDown(event, this)" style="width:100%">this text should appear in the text area not just in the console</input> ==$0
```

I am very gratful for any kind of help.

Answer (score 0):

Your using the input field wrong, it doesn't have a closing tag. You should have:

```html
<input id="textInput" class="input responsive-column" placeholder="Type something" type="text" onkeydown="/*globals CanvasJS */
            ConversationPanel.inputKeyDown(event, this)" style="width:100%" value="this text should appear in the text area not just in the console"/>
```

You can also use a textarea element:

```html
<textarea id="textInput" class="input responsive-column" placeholder="Type something" type="text" onkeydown="/*globals CanvasJS */
            ConversationPanel.inputKeyDown(event, this)" style="width:100%">this text should appear in the text area not just in the console</textarea>
```

Comment: Hi chinloyal, thank you very much for your help! ... I needed to solve this problem with a slightlydifferent approach